# Can syntax highlighting be enabled for Groovy DSL with custom file extension in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, groovy, dsl

We are working on creating a custom Domain Specific Language in Groovy. We plan to use a custom file name extension ( for example .xyz ) for the code written in this DSL.
I and using eclipse as my IDE. 
When i change the extension of the file from .groovy to .xyz, eclipse considers this file as a text file and removes all the color codes that are associated with a groovy file.

Is there any configuration in Eclipse that will associate the .xyz file as a groovy source file?

I see that there are a .dsld file https://spring.io/blog/2011/05/09/better-dsl-support-in-groovy-eclipse  but this do not seem to be a solution to my above problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can associate a file extension with a editor content type in the Eclipse Preferences. Go to the 'General > Content Types' page in the preferences.

Find and select the Groovy content type in the list and click 'Add..' to add your '.xyz' extension to the list of file associations.

You can also do this in an Eclipse plugin using `org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes` extension point.

Comment: Thanks Greg. This solves my immediate problem of syntax highlighting. We are exploring creation of .dsld files for adding additional editing support.